# Furnace questions

Tags: furnace

You set your thermostat temperature to 75 degrees and your furnace cycles on and after sometime it reaches that temperature of 75 degrees. My question is for example, for an hour your house temperature is still reading 75 degrees on your thermostat should your furnace still cycle on (When it cycles on for roughly5 minutes stays off for roughly 15 to 20 minutes)? If so for how long?

Comment: "For how long?" varies with "How cold is it outside?" It's as long as is required to meet the heating load, based on temperature differential, air leakage, furnace size, insulation levels, etc... The whole idea of a thermostat is that you set it to 75, and the house stays at 75, rather than cycling between 50 and 90.

Answer (score 2):

Thermostats come in 2 styles mechanical and electronic. Both have a dead band.
What is a dead band this is a zone that the thermostat allows the furnace to continue heating above the set point or continue cooling below the set point.

Some have a dead band of +-2 degrees or A 4 degree differential from turning on to turning off.
The dead band increases the run time so less starts are required lowering the power Bill. On my electronic thermostats I run +0-3 for cooling and +3-0 for heating the 1 degree costs slightly more but reduces the temp variation in the home.

If there was no dead band the furnace may be cycling on and off within 1 minute and starting the fan and heating the ductwork or starting the compressor and cooling the ductwork costing much more and rooms farthest away from the thermostat may see extremes in their temperature.

So how long would be based on the dead band and outside temperature. Mechanical thermostats may be off by a few degrees especially if mounted on an external wall. Electronic thermostats usually have the ability to shift the calibration point. Mechanical stats can be adjusted but I have seen many that are damaged because folks did not understand the built in dead band.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that the thermostats are mass produced and have a tolerance of 1 to 2 degrees. When you thermostat reads 75, it can actually be anywhere from 75.1 degrees to 75.9 degrees and considering the tolerances, anywhere from 74 to 76 degrees.  So yes, your furnace can cycle on at 75 when set to 75. Running for 5 minutes then off for 15 to 20 is normal from my experience. Part of the inaccuracies is due to the linkage, either mechanical or electrical, between the contacts turning on and off the furnace and the display. I've had to or three thermometers stationed right at my thermostat and all of them had different reading.